# Is there something wrong with this HTML?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
         <p>I love mixing my background of art and design with web development and design. In my spare time I love playing sports and board games.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
         <p>About</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there something wrong with this? I am trying to make it split down the page but it won't seem to split. The paragraph part of it is going past the split every time.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: what is p1 and p2????

Comment: there is nothing like `p1` or `p2` in html

Comment: Well, there are no `p1` or `p2` elements defined in HTML. Besides that, no.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using the float property in CSS for both p1 and p2 (is it okay to add numbers after p?). Does float mess with the splitting?

Comment: @maritaslag In case it wasn't clear from the 3 other comments, no, it's not okay to add numbers after `p`.

Comment: As Mike mentioned, there are no p1 or p2 tags in html. If you want to identify them, use the id property. <p id='1'>.

Comment: @Brad I see! thank you! So if I have more than 1 "p" but want them to have different style I would just create a class and then apply it to the HTML right?

Comment: I fixed the "p" situation, thank you all for that! But it still won't split...?

Comment: @maritaslag It's only going to split at certain resolutions, and only if you've got the viewport meta tag correctly configured.

Comment: If it helps at all, I'm using CodePen. It's weird because if I open a sample CodePen source code that is showing a split and copy/paste the exact same thing to my own, it won't split on mine. Does it matter that I have a large background image?

Comment: Please include a [MCVE]. Don't make us guess what information is missing.

Answer (score 2):

No tag named p1. Paragraph is simply written as `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing

```
<div class="container">
 //Your code
</div>
```

Can't see what p1 and p2 tags people keep talking about, so my guess is that you are missing the *container* class